# Upgrade-SPContentDatabase fails after installing updates

Tags: sharepoint, updates

after installing the latest MS Updates for SharePoint 2016, the psconfig.exe fails with

> The upgraded database schema doesn't match the TargetSchema

This should be solved with upgrading all the Content Databases before executing PSConfig/PSConfigUI with: `Get-SPContentDatabase | Upgrade-SPContentDatabase` but this also fails with error:

> Upgrade-SPContentDatabase : Invalid column name 'TS_LINE_ADDED_IN_TS'.
>   Invalid column name 'TS_LINE_ADDED_IN_TS'. In line: 1 character: 25
>   + Get-SPContentDatabase | Upgrade-SPContentDatabase
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...ContentDatabase: SPCmdletUpgradeContentDatabase)
>   [Upgrade-SPContentDatabase], SqlException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletUpgradeContentDatabase

Can someone help me?